# Firewall-cmd rule for filtering incoming source addresses

Tags: linux, centos, firewalld

I'm trying to setup a `firewall-cmd` **rule** for incoming **source IPv4 addresses** using **CentOS 7**.

At present, I've managed to `add-port` for `zone=public`, but cannot find a way to do "granular filtering" for external access - like what is mentioned above.

Is there any means to do that other than using [rich language](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/configuring_complex_firewall_rules_with_the_rich-language_syntax)? If (or not) so, how I'd go about using either of them for this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per link

The format or structure of the rich rule commands is as follows:

```
rule [family="rule family"]
    [ source [NOT] [address="address"] [mac="mac-address"] [ipset="ipset"] ]
    [ destination [NOT] address="address" ]
    [ element ]
    [ log [prefix="prefix text"] [level="log level"] [limit value="rate/duration"] ]
    [ audit ]
    [ action ]
```

to deny 8.8.8.8 from both tcp and udp on port 80

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='source address=8.8.8.8 port=80 deny'
```

usual convention apply

- `source address=192.168.117.0/24`
- `destination not address=8.8.8.8`

It seems full syntax must be use to query (`--query-rich-rule='..'`) or remove (`--remove-rich-rule='..'`)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to block a specific IP address from accessing the server, the [`fds`](https://github.com/dvershinin/fds) frontend is easier to work with. It uses FirewallD and IP sets behind the scenes, but is providing an easier CLI interface compared to that of `firewall-cmd`:

#### Set up

```
sudo yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
sudo yum -y install fds
```

#### Block an IP

```
sudo fds block 1.2.3.4
```